# Why does SwiftUI animate List items differently after index removed?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I've really struggled to understand why this may be happening and I'm at a loss.

The situation seems to be that animations are different based on whether or not an item has previously existed at the index of the array the animating item occupies.

Here is the code I'm using:

```swift
  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Profile.lastUsed, ascending: true)],
    animation: .spring()
  )
  private var profiles: FetchedResults<Profile>

  var body: some View {
    List() {
      ForEach(profiles, id: \.id) { profile in
        ProfileView(profile)
      }
    }
    .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
    .toolbar {
      Button(action: addItem) {
        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
      }
      Button(action: deleteItem) {
        Label("Remove Items", systemImage: "minus")
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func addItem() {
      let profile = Profile(context: viewContext)
      profile.id = UUID()
      profile.lastUsed = Date()
      do {
        try viewContext.save()
      } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
      }
  }
  
  private func deleteItem() {
    if profiles.last != nil { viewContext.delete(profiles.last!) }
    
    do {
      try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
      // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
      // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
      let nsError = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
  }

struct ProfileView: View {
  @State var isPopover = false
  var profile: Profile;
  
  init(_ profile: Profile) {
    self.profile = profile;
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: { self.isPopover.toggle() }) {
      ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
          .fill(Color(NSColor.separatorColor).opacity(0.75))
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text("\(profile.id!)").font(.headline)
          Text("Profile last used \(profile.lastUsed!, formatter: itemFormatter)").font(.body)
        }.padding(12)
      }
    }
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    .padding(.bottom, 8)
    .popover(isPresented: self.$isPopover, arrowEdge: .trailing) {
       PopoverView()
    }
  }
}
```

And the resultant effect can be seen [here](https://vimeo.com/458744899)

I'm not sure if I'm missing some information here or if it is a bug, as this is on Big Sur Beta 4.

Comment: And yes, and no. It is due to List views reuse/caching. First time you add (on video) the view is created so resized/inserted/presented, but second time it is only inserted/presented, because when you delete item view was not deleted. To try to fix it needed code of ProfileView to reproduce your effect locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: { self.isPopover.toggle() }) {
      ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
          .fill(Color(NSColor.separatorColor).opacity(0.75))
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text("\(profile.id!)").font(.headline)
          Text("Profile last used \(profile.lastUsed!, formatter: itemFormatter)").font(.body)
        }.padding(12)
      }
    }
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    .padding(.bottom, 8)
    .animation(nil)          // << here !!
...
```